# Can I use as "She hates to spend money or to give money away." instead of "She hates to spend money or give money away."?

Tags: to-infinitive

Here is a sentence which is correct.

> Sentence 1.
>   She hates to spend money or give money away.

I wonder the Sentence 2 is also right.

> Sentence 2.
>   She hates to spend money or to give money away.

The only difference is the "to" existing or not before "give money away".

Thank you.

Comment: Both sentences are equally correct and acceptable as written.

Comment: Or *She hates to spend or give away money*, removing all repeated words. Note that *She hates to spend or give money away* wouldn't quite work for some native speakers, because it implies the "full" version would contain ***...to spend money away...***, which is invalid. But it would definitely occur sometimes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the explanation. Maybe if it would not be bothering you much, may I ask you for some more detailed explanation about what you covered about **to spend money away**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The version with *to* repeated before the second verb sounds better to me. But context and communicative intent may favor one or the other.